# Get generic type of T in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, typetoken

I have this generic method:

```
class Deserializer<T : Any> : ResponseDeserializable<T> {
    override fun deserialize(reader: Reader): T? {
        val type =  object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(reader, type)
    }
}
```

but the `val type =  object: TypeToken<T>() {}.type` is returning "T" to me, instead the type of the class passed.

Is there a way to get the type of the class passed as "T"?

Comment: Did you try `reified` the line, like that:
`inline fun <reified T : Any> deserialize(reader: Reader): T?`

Comment: Yes, but If I do this, I will cannot override deserialize method(because the signature of the same). I also cannot do <reified T: Any> because I am already using "T" in the class generic type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `Deserializer` body is compiled only once, the compiler cannot create different classes for `object : TypeToken<T>() {}` with different concrete types substituting the type parameter `T` (thus it just leaves `T` as it is), while this condition is essential for generics reification with `TypeToken` to work.

You can only obtain the concrete type with `TypeToken` where a concrete type is present in the source code **or** inside an `inline` function with a `reified` type parameter.

You can fix your code by adding a `TypeToken` parameter to the constructor of `Deserializer` and using an `inline` factory function:

```
class Deserializer<T : Any>(
    val typeToken: TypeToken<T>
) : ResponseDeserializable<T> {

    override fun deserialize(reader: Reader): T? {
        val type = typeToken.type
        return Gson().fromJson(reader, type)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> deserializerOf(): Deserializer<T> = 
    Deserializer(object : TypeToken<T>() {})
```

Usage example:

```
val deserializer = deserializerOf<MyType>()
```

This will work because, when the function is inlined, the compiler transforms its body for each of its call sites, and the transformations include substituting the reified type parameters with the concrete types.